# Replace accented or special characters using sed

Tags: accents

I want to change `á é í ó ú` and `ñ` to `\'a  \'e \'{\i} \'o \'u` and `\~n`  in all my .tex files. I´ve used the code

```
find . -name “*.tex” -type f -exec sed -i “s/á/\'a/g” {} \;
```

but it doesn't work. Somebody has any sugestion?

Comment: you want to use ascii double quotes for the sed argument `"` not  `“`

Comment: why do you need to do this? tex can handle the accented characters without this replacement.

Comment: I don't know why, but there are a couple of machines that aren't my property, where just making this change makes everything compile well. In these machines TexMaker says that there are characters that cannot change from one encoding to another, and it has to do with accents.

Comment: if the file is badly encoded, sed will be no more able to recognise accents than texmaker. You need to save the file in a known encoding, preferably utf-8 and make sure texmaker is using that encoding

Comment: You also need ascii double quotes for the find argument.

Comment: I ran the command (with straight instead of smart double quotes) and got the desired result.

Comment: Can I see your code?

Comment: find . -name "*.tex" -type f -exec sed -ibak "s/á/\'a/g" {} \;

Comment: Okay, it does work. It's better for me to do this than to change something in someone else's machine! I accept this as an answer. Thank you